# Doubt on application of uncertainty principle for an ion trap

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-information, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, ion-traps

[Ion trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_trap) involves the application of an electromagnetic field to suspend and confine a charged particle.

At the centre of this picture, you see a saddle shape. This means that the ions are pushed back to the middle. The trap works by rapidly oscillating the potential, so the confinement is in *all directions of the plane*. They are confined in the perpendicular direction too by putting a fixed opposite voltage on the pin-like electrodes at either end of the trap. The oscillating field provides a minimum in the total energy of the ion at the trap centre.

Now that we have localized the ion to the dimensions of, say less than a nanometer, and since the ion seeks the place of minimum micromotion, has the Heisenberg's uncertainty principle been a bit relaxed?

[image]

<sup>Potential experienced by the ion

Courtesy: [Physics website of Oxford university](https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/research/ion-trap-quantum-computing-group/intro-to-ion-trap-qc)</sup>

Comment: No. As the position of the particle becomes confined its momentum becomes more uncertain

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it also try to minimize its movement due to potential applied, in which case, can momentum be known with fair certainty?